# Can I convert Wizz air credits into cash?

Tags: wizz-air

I booked a ticket with Wizz air from Amman to Milan. However, Wizz air cancelled the flight and refunded me with Wizz credit. I would like the money to be in my bank account. I searched their website but could not find any way to get the credit into my bank.

How can I get the Wizz air credit in cash?

Comment: If you have agreed to the flight being refunded as vouchers, you can't get cash

Comment: Did you get the Wizz credits automatically or have you requested them by clicking somewhere?